# How to inject HiltViewModel into Java class

Tags: kotlin, viewmodel, dagger-hilt, inject

I'm using such code to inject viewmodel into kotlin class

```
val viewModel  = viewModel<UserViewModel>()
or
private val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()
```

but how to inject viewModel into Java class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      // Step 1: Create a ViewModelProvider
    ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory factory = ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(getApplication());

    // Step 2: Retrieve the ViewModel instance
    viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(MyViewModel.class);

    // Now you can use the viewModel instance in your Java class
    // ...
```